# Custome UIView behaves than actual UIView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I created custom UIView class in storyboard say "XXX". I have created object in view controller. The object name is "YYY". Now i'm trying to call animateWithDiruation method.

```
 @IBOutlet var YYY: XXX!

    YYY.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        //changes to animate
    })
```

It throws error. XXX does not have member named animateWithDuration.

But the below code works fine.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
    //changes to animate
})
```

How to call animateWithDuration method using custom UIView class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `animateWithDuration` is a static(class) method which you run on `UIView` class.

You should animate your YYY custom view using `UIView.animateWithDuration`, for example:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
    //changes to animate
    XXX.center = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the docs, you will see that animateWithDuration is a class method. Meaning, you can only access it using UIView.animateWithDuration ....